# How to avoid the name conflicts in pandas's `query` method?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to query by index in a dataframe as following:

```
Python 3.8.5 (default, Aug  5 2020, 09:44:06) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.15.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: pd.__version__
Out[2]: '1.0.5'
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3, 4]}, 
               index=pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.date_range('20200101', '20200102'), name='datetime'))

In [4]: end = pd.to_datetime('20200101')
In [5]: df.query('datetime <= @end')
```

However, the above code lead to an exception:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-0656de8e993d> in <module>
----> 1 df.query('datetime <= @end')

e:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in query(self, expr, inplace, **kwargs)
   3229         kwargs["level"] = kwargs.pop("level", 0) + 1
   3230         kwargs["target"] = None
-> 3231         res = self.eval(expr, **kwargs)
   3232
   3233         try:

...

e:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\ops.py in evaluate(self, env, engine, parser, term_type, eval_in_python)
    434             # base cases
    435             if self.op in eval_in_python:
--> 436                 res = self.func(left.value, right.value)
    437             else:
    438                 from pandas.core.computation.eval import eval

TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'type' and 'Timestamp'
```

It seems that pandas is confused the **index datetime** with build-in type **datetime.datetime**, how to solve this problem (with query and keep the index name)?

**EDIT**

I have more test and get some interesting result:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['T0', 'T1'], ['A', 'B']], names=['datetime', 'count'])

In [3]: frame = pd.DataFrame({'isnull': range(len(index))}, index=index)

In [4]: frame
Out[4]: 
                isnull
datetime count        
T0       A           0
         B           1
T1       A           2
         B           3

In [5]: frame.query('count == "A"')
Out[5]: 
                isnull
datetime count        
T0       A           0
T1       A           2

In [6]: frame.query('isnull < 2')
Out[6]: 
                isnull
datetime count        
T0       A           0
         B           1

In [7]: frame.query('datetime == "T0"')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\home\tools\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
...
pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: False
```

- the names like `count` and `isnull` works in `query`;
- if the `dtype` of `datetime` in index changed to `str`, the query raise an `KeyError` rather than `TypeError`.

Comment: use index instead, `df.query('index <= @end')` i think you would have the same issue if you used an actual method as a column name and tried to access it via dot notation `df['count']` and `df.count` for example

Comment: @Manakin I have tried dataframe with column named `count`, and it works fine using `query`

Comment: I think Manakin was refering to `df['datetime']`, this will throw error, since there is no column named `datetime` @esse

Comment: @MrNobody33 I add some results in my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the name of the index that in this case it's the same as a type of pandas, as you can see in the error. So as Manakin said in the comments, you can use `index`, instead of `datetime` to do the query:

```
df.query('index <= @end')
```

Or also, change the index name to avoid the ambiguity:

```
df.index.name='dates'
df.query('dates <= @end')
```